# What are the limitations of the "free" VSTS?

Tags: azure-devops

I'm currently evaluating VSTS, but I'm concerned about some of the limitations of the "free" version.

I believe there is a 10 GB storage limit. Is this for everything (source code, build artifacts, packages, etc.), and is there any way to increase this?

I've also seen a limit of four hours of build time per month - that's only 12 minutes a day! I'm finding that even a small solution takes a few minutes to build; our "real" solutions are significantly larger and we often check in code many times during a typical day.

What happens if this build limit is exceeded? Are you prevented from building until the next billing month?

Am I right in saying that purchasing a hosted pipeline (aka "hosted CI/CD") at US$40/month would overcome this limit?

Comment: You can use private agent (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/agents/v2-windows), and the storage limit is based on your agent machine, and the build time is unlimited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure where you got that idea from. There are no limits on storage for source code, packages, build artifacts, or test results that I'm aware of.

There is a [10 GB limit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/agents/hosted#capabilities-and-limitations) for hosted build agents, but that just refers to the amount of source code/build output that can be present on a single instance of the hosted agent. Honestly, if your source code is anywhere near 10 GB, you're going to find the hosted build agents to be inadequate anyway.

Regarding build, refer to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/billing/buy-more-build-vs). You can either pay for [Microsoft-hosted agents](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.build-release-hosted-pipelines) or purchase [private pipelines](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.build-release-private-pipelines), which enable you to set up your own build infrastructure. Every VSTS account has one free private pipeline, so you actually don't need to pay anything extra at all, assuming you take on the job of maintaining your own build/release server and only need one thing to run at a time.

Comment: So the limit only relates to builds? E.g. source that the build "gets", and build output, contribute to this limit? Presumably the limit will be affected the more builds you have, and the more old builds you retain? I'm surprised artifacts don't contribute to the limit as I see these as build outputs. Do these not get stored on the agent then?

Comment: The reason I asked about the limit in the first place was because people are complaining it's not enough: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/17648914-increase-the-hosted-build-agent-size-limit-from-10. This made me a bit suspicious that there's more to it than just the storage needed during a build.

Comment: @AndrewStephens No, the limit is purely because the hosted build agents only make 10 GB of disk space available **while the build is running**. Every build starts fresh. Your source code + the outputs of the build process for a single build must be under 10 GB.

Comment: Artifacts can be downloaded for past builds so I'm assuming these aren't stored on the agent and therefore don't contribute to the 10gb limit?

Comment: @AndrewStephens Yes, the build artifact is stored in VSTS instead of agent (Visual Studio Team Services/TFS publish location option)

Answer (score 1):

The "free" VSTS, as you say, has a limit of five users with basic access. For stakeholders, you can add as many as you need.

For build, you have up to 4 h/month. But if you want to use CI, that is probably not enough. If you will use it only to build at certain points manually, it could be a start.

With your free account you could download and install a private build agent. This will have no minute limits. So you could implement a CI build, for instance.

Hosted agents have up to 10 GB of storage. But again, if you use a private one, you will not have this limit. For other stuff like code, workitems and so on as far as I know there are no limits.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/billing/buy-more-build-vs) you can see how to buy more hosted agents.

Depending on your needs, you could go after Microsoft Action Pack, which will give you internal licenses for other Microsoft software as well as more VSTS users via an MSDN subscription.

Since you are evaluating, you can take a look at [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/collaborate/rate-limits) for more global resource limitations, but they are pretty high, since Microsoft itself uses VSTS.